# Select2 searching related keywords to tags

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-select2, keyword, tagging

I'm currently developing a currency converting app using select2 to load the currencies.

I want the user to be able to look for a currency by typing the country. For example:

- If the search for *America* -> USD should come up
- If the search for *Spain*, *Italy* -> EUR should come up

I keep looking through the Select2 docs but can't find how to add related keywords to my currency tags.

See code below:

```
<select id="to" class="js-example-templating" onchange="convertCurrencyRight()" onkeyup="convertCurrencyRight()" >
        <option value="USD" selected>USD </option>
        <option value="EUR"  >EUR </option>
</select>
```

[An Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcqcL.jpg)

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using custom [`matcher`](https://select2.org/searching) and [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) functions

```js
$(".select").select2({
  matcher: matchCustom
});

function matchCustom(params, data) {
  // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
  if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
    return data;
  }

  // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
  if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
    return null;
  }

  // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
  // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
  if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
    return data;
  }

  // custom search using lookup data
  if ($(data.element).data('lookup').toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
    return data;
  }

  // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
  return null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select class="select" style="width: 200px">
  <option value="USD" data-lookup="America" selected>USD </option>
  <option value="EUR" data-lookup="Spain, Italy">EUR </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice one, this works perfectly. The only thing, how can I make matcher work together with templating (templateSelectiom & templateResult). They don't seem to like each other